# More columns than column names when I have sentences

Tags: r, csv

Because in one column I have sentences, for example

```
    id  gender  ratings  name  thoughts
1    A     F      5       Amy   I think that,... and "City of Stars" is...
2    B     M      4       Bob   Good/Bad is......
```

How can I read them in R?

```
movies <- read.table("moviesclean.csv", header = TRUE, quote = "",sep="\t",stringsAsFactors=FALSE,encoding="UTF-8")
```

this one is not working for me...

Comment: Well do tabs appear inside the text of the `thoughts` column?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen probably not, only space between words

Comment: Then it should be working AFAIK.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen but the sep="\t" is not working....

Comment: Maybe you should update your question with what actually is happening.